# an error occurs when launching the application 404 Error not found JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I created a simple login page and the ability to log out. my project has jsp and Servlets. the problem is that when I launch the page, a 404 "not found" response comes.

yes, I tried to move the folder with jsp behind WEB-INF and it seemed to go away, but I need the folder with jsp to be in WEB-INF

[the error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J7rM.png)

the index.jsp

```
type here<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<c:redirect url="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/login.jsp"/>
</html>
```

pom.xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testwebapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testwebapp</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>   ${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[my GitHub Repository:](https://github.com/paveltesla/ServletProject.git)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding login.jsp in mapping of web.xml and everything worked

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="4.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/view/jsp/login.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```